# PowerBI Dynamic Row Level Security not working in Service

Tags: powerbi, row-level-security

I have created and tested a rule in the powerbi app that works fine in "view as", but when I publish my dataset with the rule, the report in the service is not working.

I am not sure if it has anything to do with that I am an admin on the project and using my own email to test out the filtering (though this isn't a problem in the app). Any thoughts? I realize this might be quite vague. My organization is still rather new to PBI.

```
Var CompanyPCC = CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( 'User Access'[PCC]),
        FILTER ( 'User Access', 'User Access'[Login] = USERPRINCIPALNAME()  )
    )
RETURN 
OR(
"ALL" IN CompanyPCC,
PATHCONTAINS(CompanyPCC,'Company'[Company PCC])
)
&& 

Var Country= CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( 'User Access'[Country] ),
        FILTER ( 'User Access', 'User Access'[Login] = USERPRINCIPALNAME()  )
    )
RETURN 
OR(
"ALL" IN Country,
PATHCONTAINS(Country,'Company'[Company Profile Country])
)
&&

Var Brand= CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( 'User Access'[Brand] ),
        FILTER ( 'User Access', 'User Access'[Login] = USERPRINCIPALNAME()  )
    )
RETURN 
OR(
"ALL" IN Brand,
PATHCONTAINS(Brand,'Company'[Company Brand])
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For RLS to work, a user needs to have read only permission in the workspace. Members or admins see everything by default. See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-rls#using-rls-with-workspaces-in-power-bi